# Reload Application Context

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to setup an ASP.NET web application so that when I drop an updated dependent assembly into the BIN directory, the app will recognize it and reload, and begin using the new assembly?

If so, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Update: I just created a simple test app with 2 projetcs...1 web application and 1 class library.  The Web Application has a project reference to the Class Library.  The Interface is implemented in a class in the Class Library and has a single string property.  The web application has one page that shows the value of the implemented property.

I then updated the implemented property to use a new value, and copies just the ClassLibrary DLL to the publish web app.  I refreshed the browser, and the updated value was displayed.

Can this be replied upon?  It seems the updated bin reloaded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... as you have surmised, this behavior is already built into ASP.NET.  And yes, it is quite reliable.